# How to swap sides of side-by-side video chat interview?

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere, video-editor, interview

I recorded a video interview using Zoom Cloud Meetings, and the 2 participants appear to be looking away from each other instead of towards each other:

[image]

How can I swap the sides?

The resolution is 1920x1080, and I want to keep the black bars on the top and bottom.

I have FFmpeg and Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2017 and other tools available.

P.S. This has nothing to do with a similarly-titled question relating to 3D Vision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ffmpeg,

```
ffmpeg -i recording.mp4
  -filter_complex
     "[0]split[a][b];
      [a]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[r];
      [b]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:0[l];
      [l][r]hstack"
  -c:a copy switched.mp4
```

Two crops of the video are made and then joined in opposite order.

---

Using swaprect filter,

```
ffmpeg -i recording.mp4 -vf "swaprect=w/2:h:0:0:w/2:0" -c:a copy switched.mp4
```

Comment: You are a genius! Wow! I appreciate your help so much. It worked.

Comment: Same can be done with swaprect filter.

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol That would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Premiere Pro, duplicate your footage (excluding audio) and place it directly on a track directly above or below.

In the Effects Panel, set the one position of one clip to 0px and the second clip to the exact width of your frame (which in this case would be 1920px).

If you wish to make additional edits to both clips, you should 'nest' both the video clips by right-clicking on the two videos clips and selecting 'Nest...'.

You should also re-link the audio to the nested clip.